# Jquery select closest class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.b').val(1);//NOT WORKING
        $(this).next().next('.b').val(1);//WORKS
    });
});
</script>

<button>Click me</button>
<input class="a" type="text" />
<input class="b" type="text" />

<button>Click me 2</button>
<input class="a" type="text" />
<input class="b" type="text" />
```

I try to select the closest class, I have tried closest(), but its not working.

I tried next().next(), it works, anyone why?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? How about reading the documentation for [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per doc for closest

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

and inputs are siblings to clicked buttons.

you can also use:

```
$(this).nextAll('.b:eq(0)').val(1);
```

even `$(this).next().next().val(1)` will work instead of `$(this).next().next('.b').val(1)`

Comment: well nextAll will also get other input with `.b` class sibling. and you just want the first next out of it. and `.eq(0)` will get the first element in matched array.

Comment: how about closest() ?

Comment: that would be unnecessary.